# URL of nginx-thrift or media-frontend show : 192.168.49.2 refused to connect page on the browser #215

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-config

The pods for nginx-thrift and media-fronted are running but still i have the issue that is: when i try

```
$ minikube -n social-network service --all
```

and see the URL of nginx-thrift ,media-frontend and jaegar-out
The URL for jaegar-out works properly and opens ups the jaeger UI but when i try going to URL of nginx-thrift or media-frontend they show :
`192.168.49.2 refused to connect page` on the browser

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly using `ClusterIP` type services which cannot be connected from outside the cluster, under normal conditions. You can try setting your service type to `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` and it should be accessible. You can read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) in the official documentation.

Comment: I'm using NodePort and for all the services. It is possibly some specific port issue, Jaeger is working properly and i was able to run media-frontend wih targetPort : 80 but nginx-thrift is still not working ?